# Error: Invalid stream reference provided Laravel 6

Tags: php, file, laravel-6, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel 6 with Passport to create an API, I'm trying to create an endpoint that receives 2 files, but when I try to upload the information with a Vue app I receive this error (it is sending the info as multipart/form-data):

```
{
    "message": "Invalid stream reference provided",
    "exception": "Laminas\\Diactoros\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException",
    "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laminas\\laminas-diactoros\\src\\Stream.php",
    "line": 345,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laminas\\laminas-diactoros\\src\\Stream.php",
            "line": 60,
            "function": "setStream",
            "class": "Laminas\\Diactoros\\Stream",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laminas\\laminas-diactoros\\src\\StreamFactory.php",
            "line": 41,
            "function": "__construct",
            "class": "Laminas\\Diactoros\\Stream",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\symfony\\psr-http-message-bridge\\Factory\\PsrHttpFactory.php",
            "line": 111,
            "function": "createStreamFromFile",
            "class": "Laminas\\Diactoros\\StreamFactory",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\symfony\\psr-http-message-bridge\\Factory\\PsrHttpFactory.php",
            "line": 93,
            "function": "createUploadedFile",
            "class": "Symfony\\Bridge\\PsrHttpMessage\\Factory\\PsrHttpFactory",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\symfony\\psr-http-message-bridge\\Factory\\PsrHttpFactory.php",
            "line": 65,
            "function": "getFiles",
            "class": "Symfony\\Bridge\\PsrHttpMessage\\Factory\\PsrHttpFactory",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\passport\\src\\Guards\\TokenGuard.php",
            "line": 181,
            "function": "createRequest",
            "class": "Symfony\\Bridge\\PsrHttpMessage\\Factory\\PsrHttpFactory",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\passport\\src\\Guards\\TokenGuard.php",
            "line": 131,
            "function": "getPsrRequestViaBearerToken",
            "class": "Laravel\\Passport\\Guards\\TokenGuard",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\passport\\src\\Guards\\TokenGuard.php",
            "line": 94,
            "function": "authenticateViaBearerToken",
            "class": "Laravel\\Passport\\Guards\\TokenGuard",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\passport\\src\\PassportServiceProvider.php",
            "line": 283,
            "function": "user",
            "class": "Laravel\\Passport\\Guards\\TokenGuard",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "function": "Laravel\\Passport\\{closure}",
            "class": "Laravel\\Passport\\PassportServiceProvider",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard.php",
            "line": 58,
            "function": "call_user_func"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\GuardHelpers.php",
            "line": 60,
            "function": "user",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate.php",
            "line": 62,
            "function": "check",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate.php",
            "line": 41,
            "function": "authenticate",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 105,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 683,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 658,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 624,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 613,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 170,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 130,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\spatie\\laravel-cors\\src\\Cors.php",
            "line": 28,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Spatie\\Cors\\Cors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 63,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 105,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 145,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 110,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\public\\index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\proyectos\\prixet-backend\\server.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "require_once"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to use Postman I get the same error but get I try with insomnia rest, it uploads the files with no error at all.

Is there any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Can you add the Vue code that sends the file and the PHP code for the file uploads?

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/ry81zg6) here is the back code in Laravel that receives the image.

[link](https://ibb.co/F6Dj7zq) here is the vuex actions that sends the files. (I removed a few other optional parameters when I found this error trying to figure out what happened).

Answer (score 1):

- The default "upload_max_filesize" is 2MB.
- Need to increase the size of "upload_max_filesize" in the "php.ini" file.

It works for me.

Comment: Actually, the problem was that I was running Laravel with `php artisan serve` on Windows, when I run it with apache it works and never got the error again.